# unrecognized command line option '-Zc:__cplusplus' and unrecognized command line option '-permissive-'

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, clion

I am trying to run and debug Qt6 widget application in clion.
I tried the things that u would get when do a simple search but no success.
Recently my friend told my to do this :
Add "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw810_64" to toolchain environment like this :
[image]

now when I create a Qt widget project like this :

[image]

I get these error :

```
Problems were encountered while collecting compiler information:
  g++.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-Zc:__cplusplus'
  g++.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-permissive-'; did you mean '-fpermissive'?
```

What should I do now ?
Why doesn't it recognize these options ?
I cannot change g++.exe file (or can I?) What can do about it?

I have been struggling to manage to run and debugg Qt6 project on clion the past few weeks.

God bless anyone who help me to do this.
Please Help!

Comment: Your make environment is configured for a Microsoft Visual C++ compiler and uses the command-line switches that `cl.exe` knows, which get `g++.exe` confused.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use MSVC options on a g++ command line. IIRC, g++ doesn't have (or need) an equivalent of the `-Zc:__cplusplus` option and you likely don't need to turn *off* the permissive flag, as that will be off by default.

Comment: This option, you can remove: `-Zc:__cplusplus` and the other you can replace with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pedantic-errors` to get a similar behavior.

Comment: I get this files via Qt installer and it is in Qt\Tools\mingw810_64 folder how is this for MSVC ??! @AdrianMole

Comment: I don't know *how* but the `-Zc:__cplusplus` switch is *very* MSVC-specific.

Comment: How can i change options for g++.exe file ?@TedLyngmo

Comment: Can u please tell me how can I set make environment configure for mingw? I think it alreadt is but apparently I'm wrong

Comment: I have the same problem. Has any1 found a solution for CLion?

Comment: I solved this but don't remember how (sorry). May be this : I create a qt project using qt editor then I would open the project with clion and use it. ( I could not manage to create project with clion with no error).  Btw qt projects run so slow on clion (debugging is worse)  . I am currently using qt editor for my projects. @Dariusz

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you use **MSVC**-build of Qt and not the **MinGW** one. Update your ***CMakeLists.txt*** file:

`set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH $ENV{QTDIR})`

the environment variable ***QTDIR*** is set to Qt MinGW path (e.g. *D:\Qt\6.2.3\mingw_64*).

Don't forget to add the corresponding directory ***bin*** (%QTDIR%\bin) to the ***path*** environment variable.